# How to reference or link files and folders inside a git repository to match these criteria?

Tags: linux, windows, git, github, gitlab

I've encountered a problem long time ago which I couldn't solve, but I'm curious whether it's possible to fulfill ALL of the below listed criteria at once or not.

The solution what I was looking for can:

1. somehow **refer to** an existing file or folder from another folder of the same git repo

   - basically reach the content of the file or folder from another subfolder, see the content(s) as if they were on the another path as well
   - e.g.: if `./path/to/folder` is referred from `./another_path/different_folder`, then every file in `./path/to/folder/*` is visible on path `./another_path/different_folder/*`
   - e.g.: if `./path/to/file` is referred by `./another_path/different_file`, then by reading/writing content of the `different_file`, the original file is read/modified
2. store the referred file **only once** in git repo

   - don't want to make a copy of the file to another path and maintain changes in both files simultaneously
3. be able to use multiple references for a single file
4. be able to use relative paths
5. make it work on both Windows and Linux

As if I can remember, some of the problems were while experimenting with this:

- the paths were broken after the repository was pulled to a different path (I assume they were not relative, but absolute)
- the Windows style links are special files, were not working on Linux
- the symlinks can't handle relative paths correctly on the Windows system
- the hardlinks resulted duplicating files in Windows

(I can't remember exactly which if these might be incorrect, but I'll experiment with the problem again and try to update this question.)

Is there any workaround for this problem?
Thank you for any help!

Please note (in case you would like to mark this question as a duplicate), that there are other similar questions here, but none of those questions define this set of the criteria, therefore it can't be a duplicate.